# UILocalNotification receiving notification with repeatInterval of NSYearCalendarUnit (move fire date to next fire date)

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I set the repeatInterval of my notification to NSYearCalendarUnit.
When I received the notification, I see this notification information that I log:

```
fire date = Tuesday, 13 May, 2014... next fire date = Wednesday, 13 May, 2015
```

Then I cancel the notification thinking that it will move the fire date to May 13 2015

```
[application cancelLocalNotification:locationNotification];
```

but it didn't... It really cancels the notification.

But when I didn't cancel the notification, the notification is retained however my fire date remains the same, I want it to move to 2015 and the next fire date to move to 2016

```
fire date = Tuesday, 13 May, 2014... next fire date = Wednesday, 13 May, 2015
```

Comment: how did you check the fire date remains same? i think by changing your  device date to next year ie 14 may 2015 and debug your app and check if fire date is changed or not.

Comment: by using this...  NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];... NSLog(@"Notifications: %@", notifications);

Comment: change device date as mentioned above and check again.

Comment: haha, i changed my device to next year but i can no longer run my app, i think because my contract is to expire this year... is it really because of this? i mean the fire date will move once the device date is moved to next year?

Comment: Yes,for debug you can set your repeat interval for shorter time period   like 1 minute 1 day etc and check by changing device date/time fire date changed.

Comment: for more about how to set repeat interval [check this nice tutorial about local notification](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should update the fire date of the notification.

Try with this:

```
// Maybe in your code you don't need this, but I write it anyway
[application cancelLocalNotification:locationNotification];

// This will create a new date one year past the current notification fire date
NSDateComponents * components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.year = 1;
NSDate * newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:localNotification.fireDate options:kNilOptions];

// Now you can update the localNotification fire date
localNotification.fireDate = newDate;

// Schedule it. Again, maybe you don't need this in your code
[application scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```